# Cannot Install Ubuntu 18.04 WSL

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently running 16.04 version of Ubuntu bash on Windows 10 Pro (v1803) using WSL. But, I couldn't install the newly released 18.04 Ubuntu on my machine from the windows store. Need some help.

I tried to install the 18.04 version from Windows Store. The store app just refreshes. Nothing else happen.

Tried removing v16, turned off WSL feature and started all over again. Still the same.

Tried the method from this link from [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/278152/how-to-update-the-windows-bash-shell/). It installed only 16.04 version. Not the latest 18.04.

Resetting windows store didn't work too.

Comment: Details of the problems you encountered would be helpful.  Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` installs the latest release.  Canonical has not released the upgrade yet to 18.04.  That happens at the first point (18.04.1) release due late July 2018.  There are ways of forcing the upgrade to happen sooner, but I recommend waiting on the upgrade so that you end up with a more stable upgrade as it has had some time to get bugs worked out.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019683/why-do-we-need-to-install-ubuntu-when-we-already-enable-wsl-in-win10. I hope this question can eventually be made a signpost to that one...

Comment: @ElderGeek You mean the above or the other way around?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Tried uninstalling , and reinstalling multiple times.

Comment: @ElderGeek I VTRd this question too because it was answered by Alexey Goloviznin and you can see from the screenshot in his answer that 18.04 can be installed in WSL.

Comment: @karel I'm VTR for different reasons. This question is about Ubuntu upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 in WSL, The duplicate is asking why you need to install 16.04 after activating WSL. Also the screen shot is dubbed "Fake News" as per my comment below the screen shot.

Comment: Of course it's not even a duplicate.

Comment: @karel anyway I suspect our friends voting as duplicate aren't using WSL :) I'm already dual booting 16.04 / 18.04 and getting a headache selecting GDM vs Unity vs Wayland vs Xorg. Can't imagine quad booting 16.04 / 18.04 in WSL now too.

Comment: Not sure why the "Fake News" is in the Answer's link but and can't confirm you can install Ubuntu 18.04, but can confirm that if 16.04 is installed `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` will upgrade you to 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, it worked for me - https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2874

Just log out and log in again to MS Store account!

[image]

Comment: When I go to the store, I can install a separate WSL distribution, but I wasn't able to update my "Legacy" install.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804/9n9tngvndl3q) allows one to use Ubuntu Terminal and run Ubuntu command line utilities including bash, ssh, git, apt and many more. Ubuntu 18.04 WSL is published by Canonical. WSL2 which features a true Linux kernel can be installed in Windows 10 version 2004 and later.

**Please note that Windows 10 S does not support running this app.** *Windows 10 in S Mode can’t use command-line shells like PowerShell, Command Prompt, or Bash which are commonly used in WSL. Various other developer tools are also off limits.*<sup>**[*](https://www.howtogeek.com/354057/what-is-windows-10-in-s-mode/)**</sup>

---

#### Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux

1. To use this feature, one first needs to use *Turn Windows features on or off* and select *Windows Subsystem for Linux*, click *OK*, reboot, and use this app. This step can also be performed using Administrator PowerShell prompt:

   ```
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux"
   ```
2. Restart your computer when prompted.

#### Install Ubuntu 18.04

1. Check that Windows 10 build 16215 or later is installed.
2. Open the Microsoft Store and choose Ubuntu.
3. From the Ubuntu page, click the blue *Get* button.

---

To launch Ubuntu, type `ubuntu1804` on the command-line prompt (cmd.exe), or click on the Ubuntu tile in the Start Menu.